# Jest with TypeScript and ES modules can't import "named imports" from commonjs modules

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest, babel-jest

Using TS, exports from CJS modules can be imported with syntax as if they were named ES module exports, e.g.:

```
import { sync } from 'glob';
```

However, with Jest and ES modules, when this style of import is in a test file or in a dependency of a test file, it says `SyntaxError: The requested module 'glob' does not provide an export named 'sync'`.

Going through all one by one and changing them to `import glob from 'glob';` and then calling `glob.sync()` seems to work, however when migrating some legacy stuff from another test runner to Jest this may not be an option, because there are a lot of those such imports in the codebase.

Reproduced here: https://github.com/themaskedavenger/tsjestcjerepro

Running jest with: `node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js` (as described in https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules), and using Jest config:

```
  resetMocks: true,
  testEnvironment: "node",
  testMatch: [
    "**/src/**/*.(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
  ],
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
  transform: {},
  'extensionsToTreatAsEsm': [".ts", ".tsx"],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      useESM: true,
      tsconfig: {
        allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
        declaration: true,
        esModuleInterop: true,
        jsx: "react",
        lib: ["esnext"],
        module: "es2020",
        moduleResolution: "node",
        outDir: "build",
        sourceMap: true,
        strictNullChecks: true,
        target: "ES2020",
      }
    },
  }
```

Is there a way around this, so that `import { whatever } from 'whatever'`; will work for CJS modules in jest test files?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately! There's currently an issue open, but looks like no resolution yet: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11563